# Como funciona um teclado virtual para fins de segurança?

Tags: algoritmo, segurança

Sei que tem vários posts aqui citando os prós/contras de teclados virtuais para evitar *keyloggers*, mas não vi nenhum que se aprofundou nesse ponto em específico:

> Como funcionam aqueles teclados virtuais tipo de banco? Onde, ao invés
>   de se digitar a senha, clica-se em uma combinação de números.

```
[(1, 4, 6), (2, 3, 5), (7, 8, 9), ...]
```

Qual a lógica para garantir mais segurança, obviamente além de não digitar a senha explicitamente? Se eu conseguisse capturar os cliques por `x` vezes, consigo deduzir a senha? Qual é a lógica para validar a senha e garantir a autenticação?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Esses teclados geram os números em posições aleatórias, que vão ficar variando entre os acessos do usuário. Assim, mesmo que você consiga saber quais botões o usuário utilizou, você não tem certeza da senha correta.

Por exemplo, supondo uma senha fictícia como 021793. O teclado poderia exibir as seguintes opções:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O usuário deverá utilizar os botões nessa ordem:

> **[0 ou 4]**, **[2 ou 6]**, **[1 ou 5]**, **[7 ou 9]**, **[7 ou 9]**, **[3 ou 8]**

Você já sabe que botões ele utilizou dessa vez, mas para adivinhar a senha na base da força bruta você tem um espaço de 2<sup>6</sup> = 64 combinações. Lembre-se de que o banco vai bloquear a senha após poucas tentativas com erro (a maioria dos bancos bloqueia com 3).

Da próxima vez que o usuário entrar no sistema, se você capturar os cliques de novo, terá um conjunto de 64 combinações diferentes para tentar.

Então, em tese, isso deixaria o sistema mais seguro pois ofuscaria a senha. Na prática isso é excelente para evitar que uma pessoa olhando por cima do seu ombro adivinhe a sua senha. Mas note que ao invés de tentar quebrar a senha na força bruta, um atacante poderia simplesmente fazer uma análise estatística dos botões utilizados.

Em outras palavras: ao acessar de novo a página do banco algum tempo depois, teremos outro teclado. Temos novamente 64 combinações, mas nem todas essas combinações são iguais às do conjunto anterior. Um atacante teria o espaço de adivinhação bastante reduzindo analisando somente as interseções.

Se pegarmos o teclado da foto e mudarmos:

- A primeira tecla para **[0 ou 6]**;
- A terceira tecla para **[2 ou 4]**;

Já saberemos no segundo acesso do cliente que o primeiro número da senha é 0, pois o primeiro número deve ser a interseção dos conjuntos **{0, 4}** e **{0, 6}**. O segundo número da senha também ficou mais fácil de adivinhar, pelo mesmo motivo.

---

Eu posso ter feito a adivinhação da senha parecer fácil, porém não é trivial capturar a tela do usuário. A página do banco tem seus mecanismos para evitar que você vigie os cliques. Além disso os bancos normalmente também pedem a instalação de extensões para o navegador e as vezes até programas externos para aumentar a segurança.

A única maneira de quebrar a segurança de uma senha dessas com exatidão é filmando o usuário com câmeras durante vários acessos diferentes. Talvez você consiga com uma câmera de segurança de escritório, caso os funcionários no escritório utilizem *Internet Banking*. Ou você poderia utilizar uma câmera com um zoom muito grande para filmar um vizinho enquanto ele acessa o banco. No entanto, esse tipo de ataque é tão elaborado que chega a ser cinematográfico.

Além disso, tudo o que você conseguiria seria ver o saldo do usuário. Todos os bancos que conheço ainda exigem outras formas de autenticação para permitir qualquer movimentação de conta.

Comment: Ótima resposta, parabens.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! Estava curioso principalmente pela análise estatística em relação a captura do clique. Muito bem explicado.